# Conditional Data Manipulation in Mathematica

Tags: data-structures, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to prepare the **best tools for efficient Data Analysis** in Mathematica.
I have a approximately 300 Columns & 100 000 Rows.

What would be the best tricks to :

"Remove", "Extract" or simply "Consider" parts of the data structure, for plotting for e.g.

One of the trickiest examples I could think of is :

> **Given a data structure,**
>
> Extract Column 1 to 3, 6 to 9 as well as the last One for every lines where the value in Column 2 is equal to x and the value in column 8 is different than y

I also welcome any general advice on data manipulation.

Comment: Oh boy! I might get stoned here, but the best advice I can give you to do all of the above operations on numerical data structures is to use MATLAB :D

Comment: And I am so glad I walked away from Matlab ! Mathematica`s interface is heaven to me ;)

Comment: I didn't really mean to suggest that you switch to MATLAB when your question is in mma :)

Comment: @yoda We really need a sarcasm symbol, just like the question mark and the quote symbol. I really thought you meant it seriously.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I usually reserve ‽ for when you ask me how to index a matrix, but instead I give you a roast rabbit.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I guess I'm out of my rockers today. I saw "question mark and _____ symbol" and immediately thought you were referring to the interrobang. Now I see you meant _quote_ symbol...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a generic manipulation of data in a table with named columns, I refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787901/data-table-manipulation-in-mathematica/4788373#4788373) solution of mine, for a similar question. For any particular case, it might be easier to write a function for `Select` manually. However, for many columns, and many different queries, chances to mess up indexes are high. Here is the modified solution from the mentioned post, which provides a more friendly syntax:

```
Clear[getIds];
getIds[table : {colNames_List, rows__List}] := {rows}[[All, 1]];

ClearAll[select, where];
SetAttributes[where, HoldAll];
select[cnames_List, from[table : {colNames_List, rows__List}], where[condition_]] :=
With[{colRules =  Dispatch[ Thread[colNames -> Thread[Slot[Range[Length[colNames]]]]]],
    indexRules  =  Dispatch[Thread[colNames -> Range[Length[colNames]]]]},
     With[{selF = Apply[Function, Hold[condition] /. colRules]},
       Select[{rows}, selF @@ # &][[All, cnames /. indexRules]]]];
```

What happens here is that the function used in `Select` gets generated automatically from your specifications. For example (using @Yoda's example):

```
rows = Array[#1 #2 &, {5, 15}];
```

We need to define the column names (must be strings or symbols without values):

```
In[425]:= 
colnames = "c" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[15]

Out[425]= {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "c10", "c11", "c12", 
"c13", "c14", "c15"}
```

(in practice, usually names are more descriptive, of course). Here is the table then:

```
table = Prepend[rows, colnames];
```

Here is the select statement you need (I picked `x = 4` and `y=2`):

```
select[{"c1", "c2", "c3", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "c15"}, from[table],
    where["c2" == 4 && "c8" != 2]]

{{2, 4, 6, 12, 14, 16, 18, 30}}
```

Now, for a single query, this may look like a complicated way to do this. But you can do many different queries, such as

```
In[468]:= select[{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, from[table], where[EvenQ["c2"] && "c10" > 10]]

Out[468]= {{2, 4, 6}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 8, 12}, {5, 10, 15}}
```

and similar.

Of course, if there are specific correlations in your data, you might find a particular special-purpose algorithm which will be faster. The function above can be extended in many ways, to simplify common queries (include "all", etc), or to auto-compile the generated pure function (if possible).

**EDIT**

On a philosophical note, I am sure that many Mathematica users (myself included) found themselves from time to time writing similar code again and again. The fact that Mathematica has a concise syntax makes it often very easy to write for any particular case. However, as long as one works in some specific domain (like, for example, data manipulations in a table), the cost of repeating yourself will be high for many operations. What my example illustrates in a very simple setting is a one possible way out - create a Domain-Specific Language (DSL). For that, one generally needs to define a syntax/grammar for it, and write a compiler from it to Mathematica (to generate Mathematica code automatically). Now, the example above is a very primitive realization of this idea, but my point is that Mathematica is generally very well suited for DSL creation, which I think is a very powerful technique.

Comment: @Leonid, your solution seems to handle strings columns header. In general, would you recommend to keep the header made out of strings in data-structure ? Also I must admit, I am struggling a bit to use your code, but I am still working through it to try figure out what I am doing wrong. If I fail, I will try to formulate the problem in the best way to ask for your help. Thanks again !

Comment: @500 In the particular case of table data manipulation, I'd suggest to keep the headers simply because they are more descriptive and you have fewer chances of getting the column indexes wrong - and my solution is supposed to automate the translation to index numbers. As to my code, let me know which parts may cause the confusion, and I will post better explanations. One thing that may be instructive is to look at the generated pure function for `Select` - you can do it for example with the debug utility `ShowIt` that I described in the recent question on debugging.

Comment: @500 Another good reason to keep the headers is that they provide  a level of indirection and make your solution more robust: should you wish to change the order of the columns in a table at some later time (for example by inserting some new column type into your table, or deleting an existing one, or simply exchanging columns), and the queries made with header names will remain valid, while all your  functions with explicit indexes are likely to become garbage. The true SQL queries operate with column names rather than numeric indexes for the same reason.

Comment: @Leonid, would you mind throwing an eye on this Notebook, where you will see what happen as I try to use your code. I think I am really missing something stupid, please pardon me if it is the case. Thank You again for your help : http://www.laeh500.com/LAEH/For_Leonid.html

Comment: @500 Works for me. For `select[{"RowNO", "trialNo"}, from[table],
where["condCOG" == 2]]` I get the list `{{1, 1}, {4, 2}, {8, 4}, {14, 7}, {16, 8}}` for your table. which I think is correct. If you have further questions, you can also write to me on lshifr at gmail dot com, where you can send files as attachments. So, what exactly did not work for you? Did you get the same resulting list?

Answer (score 4):

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {40, 20}]

x = 5;
y = 8;
Select[data, (#[[2]] == x && #[[8]] != y &)][[All, {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1}]]

==> {{5, 5, 1, 4, 18, 6, 3, 5}, {10, 5, 15, 3, 15, 14, 2, 5}, {18, 5, 6, 7, 7, 19, 14, 6}}
```

Some useful commands to get pieces of matrices and list are `Span` (;;), `Drop`, `Take`, `Select`, `Cases` and more. See [tutorial/GettingAndSettingPiecesOfMatrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GettingAndSettingPiecesOfMatrices.html) and [guide/PartsOfMatrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PartsOfMatrices.html),

`Part` ([[...]]) in combination with `;;` can be quite powerful. a[[All, 1;;-1;;2]], for instance, means take all rows and all odd columns (-1 having the usual meaning of counting from the end).

`Select` can be used to pick elements from a list (and remember a matrix is a list of lists), based on a logical function. It's twin brother is `Cases` which does selection based on a pattern. The function I used here is a ['pure' function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), where # refers to the argument on which this function is applied (the elements of the list in this case). Since the elements are lists themselves (the rows of the matrix) I can refer to the columns by using the `Part` ([[..]]) function.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I think the two points are disjoint.. I think @500 meant 1. How to pick columns out and 2. find elements in 2nd column & 8th column.. yada yada. In anycase, it's a simple modification from your solution above.

Comment: @yoda I didn't think so. The two requirements read as a single sentence and I interpreted them as two requirements that need to be fulfilled together. Why did you remove your answer? The Range part was something I didn't have and might come in handy when you want to select more than the few columns necessary here.

Comment: @500 @yoda 'Single Sentence it was' that's yoda talk  ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd Do the reference you gave me on matrices apply to Lists ? All the Lists ? "rectangular" Lists ? Lists//MatrixForm ?

Comment: @Sjoerd: I deleted because yours was more complete and I had misread the requirements. Anyway, undeleted now and I've changed it to just address pulling out columns.

Comment: @500 Explanation added. Does this help?

Comment: @500: Matrices are just nested lists. If you do `data//FullForm`, you'll see that the only head present is `List`. So, to answer your question, yes it will apply to lists, except for some operations that depend on the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: @500 matrices are just a particular instance of lists of lists in Mathematica. Many things that work for lists will therefor work for matrices too. See, e.g., http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VectorsAndMatrices.html

Comment: @Yoda @Sjoerd Many Thanks ! I might come back with questions as I try to implement !

Answer (score 1):

To pull out columns (or rows) you can do it by part indexing

```
data = Array[#1 #2 &, {5, 15}];
data[[All, Flatten@{Range@3, Range @@ {6, 9}, -1}]]

MatrixForm@%
```

The last line is just to view it pretty.

As Sjoerd mentioned in his comment (and in the explanation in his answer), indexing a single range can be easily done with the [`Span` (`;;`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html?q=Span&lang=en) command. If you are joining multiple disjoint ranges, using [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html?q=Flatten&lang=en) to combine the separate ranges created with [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Range.html) is easier than entering them by hand.

Comment: Perhaps it should be remarked that Range is useful here because we have several disjunct ranges that you combined using Flatten. Otherwise Span (;;) could have been used.

Answer (score 1):

I read:

> Extract Column 1 to 3, 6 to 9 as well as the last One for every lines where the value in Column 2 is equal to x and the value in column 8 is different than y

as meaning that we want:

- elements 1-3 and 6-9 from each row

AND

- the last element from rows wherein `[[2]] == x && [[8]] != y`.

This is what I hacked together:

```
a = RandomInteger[5, {20, 10}];          (*define the array*)
x = 4; y = 0;                            (*define the test values*)

Join @@ Range @@@ {1 ;; 3, 6 ;; 9};      (*define the column ranges*)

#2 == x && #8 != y & @@@ a;              (*test the rows*)

Append[%%, #] & /@ % /. {True -> -1, False :> Sequence[]};  (*complete the ranges according to the test*)

MapThread[Part, {a, %}] // TableForm     (*extract and display*)
```