# Map Select for Conditional Query in Mathematica

Tags: dictionary, select, wolfram-mathematica

Using the following list,

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
```

Is it possible to select the lists where the second value is >3. Desired Output below

```
{5, 6, 7, 8}
```

adjusting the following code that currently extract all the values >2 in a list

```
Select[#, # > 2 &] & /@ list[[2 ;;]
```

Sophisticated solutions for queries can be found here [Conditional Data Manipulation in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130276/conditional-data-manipulation-in-mathematica)

Comment: Is there a performance difference between `Select` and `Cases`?

Comment: @d00b `Select` is usually faster than `Cases` for such tasks. In this particular case `Select` is the best choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, using `Select`

```
Select[list, #[[2]] > 3 &]
```

Output

```
{{5, 6, 7, 8}}
```

Comment: I find this really powerful and easy to follow and understand. Could you adapt it to specify the elements in the list you want to extract. It could be a simple additional solution to the question mentioned above. Thanks !

Comment: @500, do you mean the element you are comparing (second column), or do you mean you want a subset of the output, such as `{6, 7, 8}`?

Comment: @500. An example of the desired output would be great. It might be of interest that `Select` can take a third argument. `Select[list, MemberQ[#, 5] &]` returns all sublists that contain a 5, and `Select[list, MemberQ[#, 5] &, 1]` returns the _first_ sublist that contains a 5.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : Both, to see how flexible Select can go.

Answer (score 6):

In this case `Select` is the simplest method, but `Pick` can also be useful in related problems.

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};

Pick[list, #>3& /@ list[[All, 2]] ]
```

To explain, `Pick` takes two lists (or nested lists) of the same shape, and returns every element from the first for which the corresponding element of the second is `True`.  (It can also accept a third argument to match for elements other than `True`.)

Here, the second column is extracted with `list[[All, 2]]` and then the test `#>3&` is mapped to each element.  This is then used as the selection list.

---

Responding to the comments by 500 requesting a generalization of the `Select` method:

```
selectByColumn[array_, index_, value_, range_] :=
  Select[array, #[[index]] > value &][[All, range]]
```

This allows one to specify:

- `array` : input array to extract from
- `index` : column index for compare
- `value` : the value to compare to
- `range` : the `Part` specification to extract from each result row

Answer (score 6):

### Speed comparison of different solutions

Interestingly, `Select` always works faster with unpacked arrays and for large arrays the difference is about one order of magnitude! Click the following table to enlarge:

[image: Table]

The code for timing tests:

```
solutions = Hold[
   Select[list, #[[2]] > 3 &],
   Cases[list, _List?(#[[2]] > 3 &)],
   Cases[list, x_List /; x[[2]] > 3],
   Cases[list, {_, x_, ___} /; x > 3],
   Cases[list, {_, _?(# > 3 &), ___}],
   Cases[list, {x___} /; List[x][[2]] > 3],
   Pick[list, UnitStep[list[[All, 2]] - 3], 1],
   Pick[list, # > 3 & /@ list[[All, 2]]]
   ];
testCases = Hold[
   {"Packed Reals", RandomReal[{0, 5}, {dim, dim}]},
   {"Unpacked Reals", 
    Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomReal[{0, 5}, {dim, dim}]},
   {"Packed Integers", RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {dim, dim}]},
   {"Unpacked Integers", 
    Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {dim, dim}]},
   {"Rationals", 
    Rationalize[#, .001] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 5}, {dim, dim}]}
   ];
timing := 
  Function[Null, 
   If[(time = First[Timing[Do[#;, {n}]]]) < .3, 
     Print["Too small timing for ", n, " iterations (dim=", dim, 
      ") of ", HoldForm[#], ": ", time, " seconds!"]; time, time]/n, 
   HoldFirst];
generateTable := 
 Labeled[TableForm[
   Transpose@
    Table[list = testCases[[i, 2]]; 
     tmgs = List @@ (timing /@ solutions); 
     d = Last@MantissaExponent[Min[tmgs]] - 3; 
     Row[{Round[10^-d*#], ".\[Times]", Superscript[10, d]}] & /@ 
      tmgs, {i, 1, Length[testCases]}], 
   TableHeadings -> {List @@ (HoldForm /@ solutions), 
     List @@ testCases[[All, 1]]}, TableAlignments -> Right], 
  Row[{"Average timings for ", dim, "\[Times]", dim, " list"}], Top]

Column[{dim = 5; n = 30000; generateTable, dim = 100; n = 3000; 
  generateTable, dim = 1000; n = 150; generateTable}, Left, 1, 
 Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

Comment: could you add `Pick[list, UnitStep[list[[All, 2]] - 3], 1]` to your testing list.  It's not as clear as the others, but it's very fast.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate Cases syntax.  The first item is skipped, the second is tested to be > 3, and we don't care about the rest of the list:

```
In[45]:= Cases[list, {_, _?(# > 3 &), ___}]
Out[45]= {{5, 6, 7, 8}}
```

I doubt this will be faster than the Select, but sometimes is clearer, especially if the test involves different data types or match some substructure.

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT:

As noted by Alexey, the following constructs are more idiomatic in Mathematica than my earlier solution

```
Cases[list, x_List /; x[[2]] > 2]
```

and

```
Cases[list, _List?(#[[2]] > 2 &)]
```

---

One solution would be to use `Cases`

```
Cases[list, {_, x_, ___} /; x > 2]
Out[1] = {{5, 6, 7, 8}}
```

This is not helpful if you want to (say) check if the 95th element is > 2. So this is a better approach where you can specify the position easily:

```
Cases[list, {x___} /; List[x][[2]] > 2]
Out[2] = {{5, 6, 7, 8}}
```

Comment: You could write it shorter: `Cases[list, x_List /; x[[2]] > 2]` or even `Cases[list, _List?(#[[2]] > 2 &)]`.

Comment: @Alexey: Thanks. In general, are the two constructs you've given faster or is it just just out of love for terseness?

Comment: @yoda I did not test them for speed but both these constructs should be faster than yours. And they present more correct method for doing such things in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @yoda I just have made time tests. The fastest construct is `Cases[list, _List?(#[[2]] > 2 &)]` but `Cases[list, x_List /; x[[2]] > 2]` is a little slower (20 to 19) than your `Cases[list, {_, x_, ___} /; x > 2]` being at the same time more general.

Comment: @yoda Interestingly, for large packed  `list`s (``Developer`PackedArrayQ``) of machine numbers your construct `Cases[list, {_, x_, ___} /; x > 2]` becomes not only faster than mine but also faster than `Select[list, #[[2]] > 2 &]`. But for large `list`s of `Rational`s and for non-packed arrays it is 30 and 17 times slower correspondingly.

Comment: @Alexey: Thanks! Please add an answer with your findings re: timings. I'm sure it will be a helpful addition to the discussion.